# How to use multiple statements within one if-clause?

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to do this in python:

```
if year and year.isdigit() and year > 0:
```

but it doesn't work. Is the number of statements limited?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? Also I am not sure how something could be a *year* and a *digit*

Comment: That's the way to do it - maybe some theoretical limit but certainly more than three. And don't check `year` if you also do `year > 0`.

Comment: "it doesn't work" - what do you mean?

Comment: @JoelCornett - `("" > 0) == True` though :P That is, `year > 0` is also `True` for a string of **any** length.

Comment: I doublecheck the user's input. He might give junk instead of a number.

Comment: @detly: touché. I made a false assumption about the comparison operator. Either way, the `year > 0` accomplishes nothing at best.

Answer (score 3):

The number of statements is not limited. It is hard to tell without seeing exactly what you mean by "doesn't work", but what you are *probably* running into is something like this:

```
>>> year = "2013"
>>> year and year.isdigit() and year > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

This happens because - like the error says - Python doesn't know how to compare a string with a number. It happens only because of the `year > 0` check, and if you limit it to that, you will get the same error (or, in Python 2, it will always be True - even for strings like `"-20"`). This goes away if you explicitly convert it to a number to do that check:

```
>>> int(year) > 0
True
```

Comment: Indeed it was an indentation-problem. Thx. I thought the number of statements is limited.

Comment: Btw this is the code:

<code>
    def valid_year(year):
    if year and year.isdigit() and year > 0:
        year = int(year)
        return year
    return None

print valid_year('0')
#=> None    
print valid_year('-11')
#=> None
print valid_year('1950')
#=> 1950
print valid_year('2000')
#=> 2000